# Adding Parent and Child Nodes in Treeview in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am attempting to display Parent and Child Nodes from SQL 2014 in a Treeview Visual Studio 2015 Form using C#. I get the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Specified argument was out of the range of
>   valid values.

Here is what the Database Table looks like:

[image]

Here is a sample of the code and surrounded in *** where the exception is being thrown:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    SqlConnection sharedSqlConnection;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Defining all Parent Tree Nodes
        TreeNode AcctParentNode;
        TreeNode CompParentNode;
        TreeNode ServerParentNode;
        TreeNode TechParentNode;

        //Establish Shared Sql Connection
        sharedSqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
        sharedSqlConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=DevOps-CTD-Prim.devops.lab;Initial Catalog=Registry;
            User ID=sa;Password=************";

        try
        {
            //We use the Open() method to establish the connection
            sharedSqlConnection.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Application.ExitThread();
        }


        //Declaring All Parent Tree Nodes
        AcctParentNode = trvAccountList.Nodes.Add("List All Accounts");
        CompParentNode = trvCompList.Nodes.Add("List All Computers");
        ServerParentNode = trvServerList.Nodes.Add("List All Servers");
        TechParentNode = trvTechList.Nodes.Add("List All Technicians");

        //Add Dummy Node
        AcctParentNode.Nodes.Add("*");
        CompParentNode.Nodes.Add("*");
        ServerParentNode.Nodes.Add("*");
        TechParentNode.Nodes.Add("*");

    }

    private void trvAccountList_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode nodeSelected, nodeChild;
        nodeSelected = e.Node;
        string strSQL = "Select * from Customer Order by Account";

        SqlCommand populateAccountTree = new SqlCommand();
        populateAccountTree.Connection = sharedSqlConnection;
        populateAccountTree.CommandText = strSQL;

        ***if (nodeSelected.Nodes[0].Text == "*")***
        {
            //This is a dummy node.
            nodeSelected.Nodes.Clear();

            SqlDataReader accountType = populateAccountTree.ExecuteReader();
            while (accountType.Read())
            {
                nodeChild = nodeSelected.Nodes.Add(accountType["Account"].ToString());
                nodeChild.Tag = accountType["LastName"];
            }
        }

    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: My guess: since it's an ArgumentOutOfRangeException, e.Node has no childnodes, so nodeSelected.Node[0] doesn't exist)

Comment: @PhilipW Next you'll be predicting water is wet, you wild-eyed hypothesist.

Comment: What if I just wanted to populate the Parent node? 

Wouldn't what I have be sufficient? I see the array starting at [0] should suffice, but really throwing me off what I could alter to fix this issue? 

Are you able to provide any examples of what you mean?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I was able to correct the issue I was facing.

Here is the code sample that I is corrected:

```
TreeNode nodeSelected, nodeChild;
        nodeSelected = e.Node;

        SqlCommand sqlCMD1 = new SqlCommand("Select * From Customer Order by Account", sharedSqlConnection);

        //This is a dummy node.
        nodeSelected.Nodes.Clear();

        try
        {

            SqlDataReader accountType = sqlCMD1.ExecuteReader();

            while (accountType.Read())
            {

                nodeChild = nodeSelected.Nodes.Add(accountType["Account"].ToString());

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Thanks for all of the help so far!